Cartopy facecolor='' not working as intended only for certain projections
I am using Cartopy 0.23.0 on a Windows 11 OS installed via conda-forge, Xarray version 2023.6.0, matplotlib version 3.8.4, and Python 3.9.19 . I am seeing strange behavior that I cannot figure out where setting facecolor='grey' only works for some projections and also only works for Robinson projection IF I specific the central longitude. Please see the attached screenshots. When it is not working it appears that it just fills the land facecolor values with the color for the max in the colorbar.
Code for Mollweide projection
Mollweide projection land plotting in yellow instead of grey
Code for Robinson projection with central longitude specified
Robinson projection working as intended with grey values over land
Any help would be welcome!!
In both instances noted above, I am running the same code, just changing the projections and getting different facecolors in the plot that is returned. This problem also exists if change from specifying the central_longitude in the subplot_kws to not specifying a central_longitude.

copy and pasting your code into the question rather than as a screenshot will allow others to try running your code and be able to help find an answer more easily
